# Get empty list after searching a specific html element in python

Tags: python, list

Given the next code, I am trying reach the last "tr" using as a basis id="rrtable".

```
<div id="rrtable">
    <table class="genTbl reportTbl">
    <tbody><tr class="alignBottom" id="header_row">
              <th><span class="lightgrayFont arial_11 noBold">Period Ending:</span></th>
                 <th><span class="bold">2020</span><div class="noBold arial_11">31/08</div></th>
                 <th><span class="bold">2020</span><div class="noBold arial_11">31/05</div></th>
                 <th><span class="bold">2020</span><div class="noBold arial_11">29/02</div></th>
                 <th><span class="bold">2019</span><div class="noBold arial_11">30/11</div></th>

             </tr>
        <tr class="secondRow" id="cas_added_row">
        <th><span class="arial_11 noBold lightgrayFont">Period Length:</span></th>
        <th><span class="noBold lightgrayFont">12 Months</span></th>
        <th><span class="noBold lightgrayFont">9 Months</span></th>
        <th><span class="noBold lightgrayFont">6 Months</span></th>
        <th><span class="noBold lightgrayFont">3 Months</span></th>
    </tr>
            
    </tbody><tbody>
        <tr> 
        ...
        </tr>
```

So far I've been trying to decompose the whole xpath command but at the very beginning I am not able to find tag div with id="rrtable".

```
print(root.xpath("//div[@id='rrtable']"))
```

Actually, the above returns an empty list.
What am I missing?

Comment: 1) what library are you using and 2) this is not valid HTML? can you please make a minimally reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Xpath does not act like JSON, in the sense that xpath will return *that element* specified by the locator, not that element-plus-all-contained-within like an object. The table element on its own is empty. The table *cells* have the data you want to eventually reach. If it didn't throw an ElementNotFound error, it did find the table.

Try getting the minimally viable data element first to check your code, then branch out and write the recursive elements to read the whole table.

Comment: Thank you BCR. Finally I succeed to get what I wanted